# Is there a way that invoke a AWS Lambda function between different VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I has two Lambda functions,
Function A access private subnet database so set in private VPC.
Function B with no VPC setting, because it needs public network.
Is there a way that can invoke function B by function A? Function A and B are synchronized.

Or if both function can be synchronized, is there any design that can solve this question?
Such as function A publish event to SNS, function B subcribe SNS?

Comment: To directly invoke a Lambda function you simply need the relevant IAM permissions, regardless of VPC network connectivity. In Python, you would call [Lambda.Client.invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) for a synchronous invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always invoke a Lambda function via [the public AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html). The Lambda function's aren't running constantly waiting for network connections. An instance of the Lambda function doesn't even exist until AWS creates an instance in order to handle an invocation request that it has received. Configuring them both to be in the same VPC wouldn't even help anything here.

Your Lambda function A either needs to be in a private subnet with a route to a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), or it needs to be in a VPC with an AWS Lambda [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html).

Comment: Just to give information; I tested with 2 lambda functions. Function A is in private subnet with no Nat gateway in a VPC. Function B (no vpc) invokes Function A  with specified policy attached "lambda:InvokeFunction" and it worked.

Comment: Yes it works fine in that direction without further setup. I thought you wanted to invoke Function B from Function A (that's what your question says), which would require the NAT Gateway or VPC Endpoint.